# Dividing an array into embed pages - Discord.JS

Tags: arrays, pagination, discord, discord.js

[image: How the array is in the database. (Array Object)]

This is how the array is in the database. (Array Object)

I want a list with all the "nome" to appear, but if the message is "large" (reach a limit that I decide on characters) do +1 page and so on

Comment: Look about message reaction collector and event 'collect', you can splice array into 2lvl array, and edit message on reaction handle.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a library for exactly this. You can either use the library as-is, or look at its source code and implement the feature your self.

*Note: The library relies on typescript, so you will have to use typescript if you want to use it as-is.*

https://github.com/Olian04/discord-dynamic-messages

```
$ npm i discord-dynamic-messages
```

```js
import { MessageEmbed } from 'discord.js';
import { DynamicMessage, OnReaction } from '../src/api';

const first = () => new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor('TOTO', 'https://i.imgur.com/ezC66kZ.png')
  .setColor('#AAA')
  .setTitle('First')
  .setDescription('First');

const second = () => new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor('TOTO', 'https://i.imgur.com/ezC66kZ.png')
  .setColor('#548')
  .setTitle('Second')
  .setDescription('Second');

const third = () => new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor('TOTO', 'https://i.imgur.com/ezC66kZ.png')
  .setColor('#35D')
  .setTitle('Third')
  .setDescription('Third');

const clamp = (num, min, max) => Math.min(Math.max(num, min), max);

export class MessageEmbedMessage extends DynamicMessage {
  private embeds = [first, second, third];
  private embedIndex = 0;

  @OnReaction(':arrow_left:')
  public previousEmbed() {
    this.embedIndex = clamp(this.embedIndex - 1, 0, this.embeds.length - 1);
  }

  @OnReaction(':arrow_right:')
  public nextEmbed() {
    this.embedIndex = clamp(this.embedIndex + 1, 0, this.embeds.length - 1);
  }

  public render() {
    return this.embeds[this.embedIndex]()
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter(`Page ${this.embedIndex + 1}`);
  }
}
```